# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I build the project I receive following error message :

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

There is no more information from Android Studio, and I can not figure out the issue. I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, You can see the actual details after clicking on the above line in the Build Output section of the build tab. You will see more details when you will click on the highlighted part drawn by pen.

**The line above where IDE is pointing in the left build output section**

[image]